# SQL matching multiple values to various values in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some issues in trying to get my query to work. I am not that efficient with SQL Server.

I have a table that has an user id column and the user id matches different values in the type column so the data looks like this

```
User | Type 
User1 | Soccer 
User1 | Tennis 
User1 | BasketBall 
User2 | Tennis 
User2 | Swimming 
User3 | Soccer 
User3 | Swimming
```

I want to be able to get all users that that belong to only one type (`Soccer`) but do not belong to any other types. So they should only have one type they belong to in the database.

Comment: Trick Question **`:)`**

Answer (score 4):

Try `HAVING` with self-join:

```
SELECT T1.[User] FROM MyTable T1
  JOIN MyTable T2
    ON T1.[User] = T2.[User]
   AND T2.[Type] = 'Soccer'
GROUP BY T1.[User]
HAVING COUNT(T1.[Type]) = 1;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f540b/11)

Comment: you will need to add a where clause with WHERE type = 'Soccer'

Comment: @hims056 **[Please see your answer](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f899/7)** Logically you are wrong.

Comment: Thank hims056! It worked. I appreciate the help. Still trying to weed myself through sql

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT [User] FROM Table1
GROUP BY [User]
HAVING COUNT([Type]) = 1
and max([Type])='Soccer'
and min([Type])='Soccer'
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f899/18)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT [User] FROM Table1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT T2.[User] FROM Table1 T2 WHERE T2.[User] = T1.[User]
             AND T2.[Type] = 'Soccer')
GROUP BY [User]
HAVING COUNT([User]) = 1
```

Comment: **[Please see your answer](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f899/7)** Logically you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f99cb/7)**

```
SELECT t1.[User] 
FROM [MyTable] t1
WHERE t1.Type = 'Soccer'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM MyTable t2
                WHERE t2.[User] = t1.[User] 
                AND t2.Type != t1.Type)
```